# Approximating fractional-octave Gaussian smoothing with non-causal variable-width IIR filters

Tags: fft, infinite-impulse-response, gaussian, smoothing, approximation

I am trying to implement fractional-octave smoothing of amplitude response data with approximated Gaussian filters, as briefly discussed in [this](https://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=13339) AES paper.
Unfortunately, no implementation details are given and I have trouble getting things to work as intended.

The "room eq wizard" software seems to do the exact same thing. In their [docs](https://www.roomeqwizard.com/help/help_en-GB/html/graph.html), the process is described in similar brevity:

> REW's smoothing uses multiple forward and backward passes of first
> order IIR filters to implement a Gaussian smoothing kernel of the
> chosen fractional octave bandwidth. [..] the time constant of the first order filter is varied
> according to the sample index to reflect the equivalent fractional
> octave bandwidth desired at the frequency of the sample.

Using actual Gaussian filters is not possible for me for reasons of efficiency.

My implementation seems to be working - almost - but finding the right values for the time constant $\tau$ turns out to be somewhat less intuitive than I anticipated.

The filter I came up with, has been modeled after the RC low-pass by a simple bilinear transform (prewarped to match cutoff). It is applied using the transposed-canonical biquad form.

Setting $\tau$ equal to the desired fractional-octave bandwidth at the current amplitude response sample index yields results that are completely off.

By trying some values "by hand", I was able to have the output match my target either in the low-end of the spectrum or the high-end, but so far I was unsuccessful in finding the correct mapping over the whole spectrum. Linearly interpolating these values across the samples also doesn't work.

Here is the smoothing filter:

```
def quick_smooth(...):
    # 1. Calculate coefficients for current iteration

    #      b0 + b1*z^-1
    # H = --------------
    #      1 + a1*z^-1

    # tau_low = i * T * np.power(2.0, 1.0/6.0) * 0.000001 # Good match for low freqs
    # tau_high = i * T * np.power(2.0, 1.0/6.0) * 0.0025 # Good match for high freqs

    n = 3.0  # Octave-fraction
    tau = T * i * np.power(2.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * n)) - T * i # Gives no usable results..

    temp = T / tau

    b0 = temp / (temp + 2.0)
    b1 = b0
    a0 = 1
    a1 = (temp - 2.0) / (temp + 2.0)

    # 2. Calculate output sample

    y = b0 * x + z1

    # 3. Update state register

    z1 = b1 * x - a1 * y

    # Return
    return y, z1
```

The filter is run multiple times, forward and backward over the data:

```
num_passes = 64 # num of backward/forward filter passes

# Create output array
fft_smooth = fft_data_db.copy()

for p in range(num_passes):
    z1 = 0.0
    for i in range(1, len(fft_data_db), 1):
        fft_smooth[i], z1 = quick_smooth(fft_smooth[i], z1, i, T, num_bins)


    z1 = 0.0
    for i in range(1, len(fft_data_db), 1):
        i = len(fft_data_db) - i
        fft_smooth[i], z1 = quick_smooth(fft_smooth[i], z1, i, T, num_bins)
```

For completeness, here are also the results I am getting when choosing $\tau$ by hand:

[image: Tau chosen for high frequencies]
[[image: Tau chosen for low frequencies][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld8Co.png)

I would be thankful for any hint in the right direction.
Any ideas on how to find the correct values for the time constant $\tau$?

-Butch

Comment: Have you tried if closer to analog response LPF filter implementation makes any difference. There are few implementations I know as like Massberg's https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Digital-Low-Pass-Filter-Design-with-Analog-Matched-Massberg/3120f3bc3d5ab05008a8908b4e8122e2ad1f356f

Comment: I have not actually tried other filters. Thanks for your suggestion! I'm assuming my problem can be solved by appropriate choice of tau. The sources I linked also don't mention any particular requirements on the accuracy. I will check out your reference! I guess oversampling would also improve the response of my filter, which is off more towards the Nyquist limit.

Comment: Matched-Z / IIM type filter implementation might also work better than BLT implementation because of these seem to work better at low frequencies and has less 'error' close the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Worth a try. Will update here in case I come across a solution.